# Download an object from OCI Object storage to OCI VM using curl

Tags: curl, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a requirement to download an OCI storage object from OCI VM using curl command. Do I need to add authentication method ? Since both storage and vm are from same account, would it not be possible to download OCI object without using auth headers?

I'm able to pass auth headers and download an object. Meanwhile I do not want to make my object public.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: [Pre-Authenticated Requests](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/usingpreauthenticatedrequests.htm).

Option 2: [Use Instance principals](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/callresources/callingservicesfrominstances.htm)

Option 3: Use [Auth Tokens](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Registry/Tasks/registrygettingauthtoken.htm) to authenticate.

Pick the option depending on your security requirements.

HTH